# Move file from subdirectory to another subdirectory in python

Tags: python, shutil, python-os

I am beginner at Python. I want to move my files from one subdirectory (from directory 1) to another subdirectory (directory 2) which I haven't created. How to do this?

```
#dir data 1 is source which contain subdir_A and subdir_B
dir_data_1:
 -subdir_A:
    -img_1.jpg
    -img_2.jpg
 -subdir_B:
    -img_3.jpg
    -img_4.jpg

#dir data 2 is the target where the files should be moved and also include subdir name
(this is what I want at the end)
dir_data_2:
 -subdir_A:
    -img_1.jpg
    -img_2.jpg
 -subdir_B:
    -img_3.jpg
    -img_4.jpg
```

So far the code that I have made look like this

```
import os
import shutil

src = 'datasetx/x/'
dst = 'datasety/'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
    k = os.makedirs(os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(root))
    for file_ in files:
        shutil.move(file_, k)
```

Can you guide me guys? Thank you

Comment: You never use `dst`.?

Comment: sorry I forgot to add. Just check now, i have updated

Comment: `Can you guide me...?` -  what are you having problems with? What is the question? Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Sorry this is first time of me using SO. My question is how to move the file from directory 1 into directory 2, including the subdirectory

Comment: Did your solution work? Did it move any files? Did it move them to the right place?

Comment: No, it has error on creating the directory. The error says exist directory

Comment: Makedirs will not create a directory that already exists. You can add a check before the call to makedirs, something like `if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(root))`

Comment: `shutil.move(dir_data_1,dir_data_2)` should do what you want all by itself. Afterwards `dir_data_1` won't exist anymore. **You should practice on fake directories**.  did you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move)?